# Android app icon as attribute

Tags: android, attr, android-theme

I have the following in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MonamiqApplication"
            android:theme="@style/monamiq_theme">
```

This works, however I would like to use an attribute for this instead, is this possible for the app icon? Im using a custom theme where I have defined the **app_icon**

I would like to use

```
<application
            android:icon="?app_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MonamiqApplication"
            android:theme="@style/monamiq_theme">
```

**attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <attr name="app_icon" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**monamiq_theme.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="monamiq_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <item name="app_icon">@drawable/icon</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: put attr.xml into res/drawable folder and to access that file android:icon="@drawable/attr.xml".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the new icons in the drawable folder, clean the project and use them with @drawable/your_image. Just replace the defaults.

Comment: Thats the conclusion I also got to, tx